# Grafana does'nt show data from InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, grafana

In Grafana i add the datasource from my InfluxDB database. When push the button test: Data source is working. When i create a graph in grafana and made a query i don't see anything. The graph shows: No datapoints. Is there something that i forgot ? I have create my own database mydb an post data with this query:{

```
    "database": "mydb",
    "points": [
        {
         "name": "cpu",
         "fields":{
                 "value": 100
            }
         }
      ]
}
```

In grafana i use this query: `SELECT min("value") AS "value" FROM "cpu" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval)` i add the time range on today. When i move with my mouse i see a tooltip with the last added data to the database.

Comment: does the query works inside an influx shell ?
depending of access mode (direct/proxy), can you reach influx server http on port 8086 ?

Comment: Yes, please test the query directly with `curl` or from the InfluxDB CLI. That will help determine where the issue lies.

Comment: With curl and cli that works. Also in the webmaster tools i see a response on the request see the printscreen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M6ub3.png